# ListView быстрое переключение отображения

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Потребовалось мне иметь возможность быстро и просто менять отображение элементов в `ListBox`. Конечно же в нем все очень неудобно, если отображение часто приходится менять, добавлять новые шаблоны и тд. Тогда я начал смотреть в сторону `ListView` с его свойством `View`.

Однако в интернетах очень мало информации о его использовании и она очень скудна. На MSDN только поверхностное описание.

[Вот тут](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/UI_WPF/level22/22_3.php) больше, но многое опять же непонятно. Там переопределили класс `ViewBase`, добавив в него свойство `public DataTemplate ItemTemplate`. Но я не могу понять каким образом это свойство применяется, ведь в `ViewBase` его нет, а значит его как то нужно посылать в `ListView.ItemTemplate`. Но как это сделано, там не сказано.

К тому же нужно так же на бегу менять панель (`ItemsPanelTemplate`). Где то нужна `WrapPanel`, где то `StackPanel`, где то вообще `UniformGrid`.

Следуя логике, я добавил в свой класс наследник от `ViewBase` свойство `ItemsPanelTemplate PanelTemplate`. Но что делать с этим дальше? Короче как мне добиться того, чтобы я меняю у `ListView` свойство `View`, указав на ресурс, и у меня полностью меняется отображение `ListView` (панели и всех элементов)?

Comment: там внизу на сайте можно странички листать, может это продолжение?

Comment: Вроде надо создать словарь ресурсов с именем **generic.xaml** как [тут](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/UI_WPF/level22/22_4.php) :-)

Comment: Сам только начал мучатся мобилами. Рискну предложить. Сделай кастомный адаптор и там в функции context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(VIEW, null); можешь поставлять  id своей view

Comment: @user2455111, там скудное описание.. я не могу догнать что для чего используется, чтобы сделать по аналогии.

Comment: @ogorank, ага, только у меня задача другая немного и мне надо разобраться с тем что там написано, чтобы сделать по аналогии. "Стиль TileView, применяющийся к ListView, вносит три перечисленных ниже изменения: ..........Изменяет ItemsPanel со StackPanel на WrapPanel, разрешая мозаичное поведение. Ширина WrapPanel устанавливается в соответствии с шириной ListView." ГДЕ ЭТО??? Укажите пальцем в кусок кода или разметки?

Comment: @Димка, у меня десктоп

Comment: Ваш вопрос решен?

Comment: @FoggyFinder, я нашел решение, но еще не готов его выложить как ответ. Кривоватое оно

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, вам нужно такое:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="150" Width="150">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- определяем нужные шаблоны -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Cyan">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="DarkCyan"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Red">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <!-- применяем один из них -->
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="LV" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Red}"/>
        <!-- кнопка для переключения -->
        <Button Click="OnStyleChangeReq" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Change style"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

и code-behind:

```
bool red = true;
void OnStyleChangeReq(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var template = (DataTemplate)FindResource(red ? "Cyan" : "Red");
    red = !red;
    LV.ItemTemplate = template;
}
```

Получается вот так:

[image: анимашка]

Ну или можно переключать через триггеры и стили, если переключаться надо в зависимости от привязанных данных из VM.

Comment: Не то. С таким подходом `ListView` не нужен, вполне хватило бы `ListBox`. Мне нужно работать именно с его свойством `View`. Смысл в том, чтобы была возможность легко менять предустановленные шаблоны не только айтемов, но и контейнера. Я ведь написал об этом в вопросе. "К тому же нужно так же на бегу менять панель (ItemsPanelTemplate). Где то нужна WrapPanel, где то StackPanel, где то вообще UniformGrid." В этом случае 2 свойства менять придется. ItemTemplate и ItemsPanel.

Comment: @iRumba: Ну да. Тогда почему бы не положить контейнеры в стиль и подменять его?

Comment: думаю, потому что мне не нужно обновлять все стили... они могут быть довольно тяжелыми. К тому же несут в себе целую кучу свойств, которые не были изменены.